# TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

It occurred when I perform this :

```py
updater = Updater('xyaz:testtsttttt-HI', use_context=True)
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

"Down grade" or "upgrade" the python-telegram-bot to the relevant version , e.g i downgraded by using "pip install python-telegram-bot==13.7" from the lastest python-telegram-bot 20.0 version, and it worked for me,
NOTE: my version might be different from yours so use the right version that wont call the error

Answer (score 7):

You should revoke the token that you just posted. Also double check [which version](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-can-i-check-the-version-of-ptb-i-am-using) of `python-telegram-bot` you are using and followng the resources that PTB provides for that version.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Issue happening if we use v20. Can't it be fixed?

Comment: @CakkMeStag What parameter is used instead of use_context in v20+?

Comment: @Shashi you can fix the problem by using code that is compatible with the version of `python-telegram-bot` that you are using. @Hadij the `use_context` argument was dropped without replacement, because it no longer has any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a version related issue and I faced the same while I was using 20.6 version.I fixed this issue by using Application class instead of using Updater.

```
from telegram.ext import Application

application = Application.builder().token(TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN).build()
```

Later you can start the bot using application object.

```
application.run_polling()
```