# I am creating a telegram bot and the following error showed up, how to fix it?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am creating a telegram bot and when I run the code to try it, it shows this error: Exception has occurred: TypeError
Updater.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters

def handle_message(update, context):
    message = update.message.text
    
    # Implement your logic based on the message content
    if message == '/help':
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="This is the help message.")
    elif message.startswith('/sayhello'):
        name = message.split()[1]  # Extract the name from the command
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"Hello, {name}!")
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Sorry, I didn't understand that command.")


def start_command(update, context):
    # Send a welcome message
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello! I'm your Telegram bot.")

bot = telegram.Bot(token='blabla')
updater = Updater(bot= bot, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.text, handle_message))

updater.start_polling()
```

I am using version 20.3 of python-telegram-bot library.
I tried downgading to 20.2 and mamyother versions, nothing worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Updater.\_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use\_context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899473/typeerror-updater-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-use-context)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and managed to resolve it by replacing 'Filters' with 'filters' and installing an older version of python-telegram-bot. Here's how you can do it:

```bash
pip install python-telegram-bot==13.14
```