# An error related to the Updater class from the python-telegram-bot library

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

```
Please fix this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\BOT-py\Adika_Taxi_services.py", line 72, in <module>
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Updater.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Updater.\_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use\_context'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899473/typeerror-updater-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-use-context)